# Infinite redirect, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying redirect non-locale URL to locale URL (/about → /en/about)
Startup.cs

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("localizedRoute", "{culture:culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}", new { controller="Home",action="Index",culture="en-US" });
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{**url}", new { controller = "Redirect", action = "RedirectToCulture", culture = "en-US" });
            });
```

RedirectController.cs

```cs
public IActionResult RedirectToCulture(string culture)
        {
            var pathAndQuery = new Uri(Request.GetDisplayUrl()).PathAndQuery;
            var redir = $"{culture}{pathAndQuery}";
            return Redirect(redir);
        }
```

It works while URL exists, but when status should be 404 I got infinite redirect: https://youtu.be/-QBunPcuvSc

How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Dont redirect if you are already on desired url. Simple if statement will do

Comment: Your catch-all route will catch all unmatched routes, including routes that weren't found, for example `/foo-not-found`. This will then redirect to `/en/foo-not-found` and hit the "default" route _again_, as it matches any URL.